# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...@types/run-sequence":

Tags: json, angular, npm

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...@types/run-sequence":'

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-24T09_59_48_560Z-debug.log
>   × Package install failed, see above.
>   The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

When I create a new angular project using "ng new newApp", Above error occured. I tried so many solutions, but did not work.

Comment: WHats the package.json file ? CAn you paste it here. Whats' there in `2020-05-24T09_59_48_560Z-debug.log`` ??

Comment: It is impossible to paste the whole code in package.json file, here. Stackoverflow doesn't allow as it is that much long

Comment: Can u check the Error line on that log file. Without it , its impossible to tell what's wrong in the npm command

Answer (score 2):

I just uninstalled angular using the command,

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Then I cleared the cache using the following command,

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then I reinstalled angular,

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then it worked successfully.